# How do I run java projects from the terminal?

Tags: java, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have 3 java files in the same folder:

*Main.java*

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a,b,c,d;
        a = Float.parseFloat(args[0]);
        b = Float.parseFloat(args[1]);
        c = Float.parseFloat(args[2]);
        d = Float.parseFloat(args[3]);
        cardano_cubic.solve_cubic(a,b,c,d);
    }
}
```

*cardano_cubic.java*

```
package com.company;

public class cardano_cubic {
    private static Complex square_root(double n){
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(n));
        return (n<0)?new Complex(sqrt,0):new Complex(0,sqrt);
    }

    public static void solve_cubic(double a, double b, double c, double d){
        System.out.println(
                (a==b&&b==c&&c==d&&d==0)?"0=0":
                (a!=0?a+"x³":"")
                +(b>0?"+"+b+"x²":b<0?b+"x²":"")
                +(c>0?"+"+c+"x":c<0?c+"x":"")
                +(d>0?"+"+d:d<0?d:"")
                +"=0"
        );

        if (a==0 && b==0 && c==0) {
            if (d==0) System.out.println("Решение - все числа");
            else System.out.println("Нет решений");
        }
        else if (a==0 && b==0 && d==0) {
            System.out.println("x1 = " + 0);
        }
        else if (a==0 && b==0) {
            System.out.println("x1 = " + -d/c);
        }
        else if (a==0) {
            Complex D = square_root(c*c-4*b*d);
            Complex x1 = new Complex(-c,0).plus(D);
            x1 = x1.scale(1/(2*b));
            Complex x2 = new Complex(-c,0).minus(D);
            x2 = x2.scale(1/(2*b));

            System.out.println("x1 = " + x1);
            System.out.println("x2 = " + x2);
        } else {
            double Q = (3 * a * c - b * b) / (9 * a * a);
            double R = (9 * a * b * c - 27 * a * a * d - 2 * b * b * b) / (54 * a * a * a);
            double sqrt = Math.sqrt(Q * Q * Q + R * R);
            double S = Math.pow(R + sqrt, 1d/3d);
            double T = Math.pow(R - sqrt, 1d/3d);

            Complex x1 = new Complex(S + T - b / (3 * a), 0);
            double c1 = -(S + T) / 2 - b / (3 * a);
            double c2 = Math.sqrt(3) / 2 * (S - T);
            Complex x2 = new Complex(c1, c2);
            Complex x3 = new Complex(c1, -c2);

            System.out.println("x1 = " + x1);
            System.out.println("x2 = " + x2);
            System.out.println("x3 = " + x3);
        }
    }
}
```

and *Complex.java*

```
package com.company;

public class Complex {
    private double re;
    private double im;

    private double eps = 10e-12;

    public Complex(double real, double imag) {
        re = real;
        im = imag;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Complex other = (Complex) o;
        return re==other.re && im==other.im;
    }

    private String format(double n){
        return String.format("%.2f",n);
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (Math.abs(im)<eps) return format(re);
        if (Math.abs(re)<eps) return format(im) + "i";
        if (im <  0) return format(re) + " - " + format(-im) + "i";
        return format(re) + " + " + format(im) + "i";
    }

    public Complex plus(Complex b) {
        Complex a = this;
        double real = a.re + b.re;
        double imag = a.im + b.im;
        return new Complex(real, imag);
    }

    public Complex minus(Complex b) {
        Complex a = this;
        double real = a.re - b.re;
        double imag = a.im - b.im;
        return new Complex(real, imag);
    }

    public Complex times(Complex b) {
        Complex a = this;
        double real = a.re * b.re - a.im * b.im;
        double imag = a.re * b.im + a.im * b.re;
        return new Complex(real, imag);
    }

    public Complex scale(double alpha) {
        return new Complex(alpha * re, alpha * im);
    }
}
```

The contents of these files are not that important, what's important is that the *Main.java* file has a reference to the *cardano_cubic.java* file and the *cardano_cubic.java* file has references to the *Complex.java* file and this runs perfectly fine in and IDE but in order to start using command line arguments it would be more convenient to run this project from a command line

So after using the `cd` command to navigate to the folder these files are located in and executing the `javac Main.java` I get this error:

```
Main.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        cardano_cubic.solve_cubic(a,b,c,d);
        ^
  symbol:   variable cardano_cubic
  location: class Main
1 error
```

Which I'm guessing means the java compiler cannot find the *cardano_cubic.java* file the code from *Main.java* is referencing to, even though they are in the same folder. How do I properly execute my program from a command line with command line arguments?

Comment: did you compile all your files?

Comment: @Stultuske yes, I did succesfully compile the *Complex.java* file which does not have any references, but running the ```javac``` command for other files with references returns the same error

Comment: so, your problem is compiling them, not running them?  did you also compile the cardano_cubic class?

Comment: your issue is caused because you are using packages. Check this link for a short explanation and example: https://www.webucator.com/article/how-to-compile-packages-in-java/

Comment: @Stultuske yes, the problem is compiling them, in my case only *Complex.java* file compiles successfully because it doesn't have references to other java files, compiling the *cardano_cubic.java* file returns the ```cannot find symbol``` error for each line where it references methods from the *Complex.java* file

Comment: @ps1nk4 so read my last comment. It points directly to an example

Comment: @Stultuske thanks a lot for the help, the article was really helpful, this solves my initial question